# Сохранить картинку в файл по определенному url

Tags: c#, xnet

Мне нужно сохранить файл(в данном случае картинку, но в общем случае любой) по его url. Я делаю гет запрос через xNet.

```
HttpResponse response = request.Get(Url);
```

Он возвращает объект response из которого можно получить либо данные с помощью ToStream либо ToString. Пробовал делать так:

```
string result = Web.GetRequest("http://picurl/pic.jpg");
//Console.WriteLine(result);
string file_path = "C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\img.jpg";
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(file_path, FileMode.Create))) 
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
    bw.Write(bytes);
    bw.Close();
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Но так в файле вместо нужных символов знаки вопроса. Я так понимаю это потому что я получил данные в строковом виде (но почему они исказились?). И чтобы сохранить в бинарном формате нужно использовать stream? В общем я не совсем в этом моменте разобрался, подскажите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете API, которое возвращает строку.

Картинка состоит из последовательности байт. Именно последовательность байт и приходит с сервера. Любое декодирование этой последовательности байт как строки - ошибка, поскольку картинка - это бинарный, а не текстовый формат.

Взглянем на то, что происходит с картинкой в программе.

1. С сервера приходит набор байт
2. Где-то он преобразуется в строку с использованием кодировки 1
3. Потом строка преобразуется в последовательность байт с использованием кодировки 2
4. Полученная последовательность байт записывается в файл.

Должно быть очевидно, что если кодировки 1 и 2 не совпадают - то в файл окажется записан мусор. В своем решении вы решили проблему путем указания одинаковых кодировок на шагах 2 и 3. Но правильной от этого программа не стала.

К примеру, если на шаге 2 попадется последовательность байт, не являющаяся корректным символом - она будет преобразована в "вопросик", и на шаге 3 этот вопросик будет уже невозможно преобразовать обратно.

Правильным решением будет выкинуть шаги 2 и 3 нафиг. А для этого надо отказаться от использования возвращающего строку `Web.GetRequest`

Вот код, который не делает никаких лишних преобразований:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest()) {
  request.Get("http://picurl/pic.jpg").ToFile(@"C:\users\alex\desktop\img.jpg");
}
```

Или вот так (для файла это бессмысленно, привожу как пример работы с потоком):

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest()) {
  var stream = request.Get("http://picurl/pic.jpg").ToStream();
  using (var file = File.Open(@"C:\users\alex\desktop\img.jpg", FileMode.Create)) {
    var bytes = new byte[1024];
    int r;
    while ((r = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
      file.Write(bytes, 0, r);
  }
}
```

Можно и массив байт целиком достать, если требуется:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest()) {
  var bytes = request.Get("http://picurl/pic.jpg").ToBytes();
  File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\users\alex\desktop\img.jpg", bytes);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. У меня почему-то ToBytes и ToStream пустое значение возвращали, поэтому сделал через преобразование строки.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин эти методы возвращают `null` если кто-то уже получил ответ. То есть если вызвать `ToString()` - то `ToBytes()` потом вернет `null`. Наоборот тоже верно.

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменил код, сейчас работает. В общем просто получаю ответ строкой. Получаю из нее байты и пишу в файл. Вдруг кому-нибудь из неофитов пригодится:

```
try
{
    resp = Web.GetRequest(pic_url);           
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("err: "+ex.Message);
    //log   
}

byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(resp);
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file_path, FileMode.Create))
{
    if (data.Length > 0)
    {       
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(data);
        bw.Close();
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```